# Проблема с подключением MemuPlay 9.0 + Appium 1.22.3

Tags: android, android-studio, эмулятор, android-emulator, appium

Который день бьюсь с проблемой подключения MemyPlay 9.0 + Appium. До этого работал с другими эмуляторами (LDplayer и BlueStacks) и все было норм.

[Папка build-tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtwgE.png)

[Папка platforms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xO1zU.png)

[Консоль adb device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Al0cX.png)

[Настройки appium inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPKfE.png)

Единственную ошибку, которую я смог найти, эту проблема с минимальной версией minsdk. В Android Studio стоит minsdk 29, а в эмуляторе 28, как это можно исправить? Я работаю в связке Python + Appium + Эмулятор(MemuPlay 9.0)

[Ошибка в Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRuRx.jpg)

[Ошибка в Appium Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqBYU.png)

Подробнее ошибка из инспектора

```
    Failed to create session. An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C:\\Users\\Default\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 127.0.0.1\:21503 install -g C:\\Users\\Администратор\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\io.appium.settings\\apks\\settings_apk-debug.apk' exited with code 1'; Command output: adb: failed to install C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\io.appium.settings\apks\settings_apk-debug.apk: Exception occurred while executing: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.endsWith(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runInstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:968) at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:179) at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:103) at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageM
```

Ошибка в appium:

```
    [Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.22.3
    [Appium] Non-default server args:
    [Appium]   port: 5566
    [Appium]   allowInsecure: {
    [Appium]     0: chromdedriver_autodownload
    [Appium]   }
    [Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:5566
    [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session
    [HTTP] {"capabilities":{"alwaysMatch":{"platformName":"Android","appium:udid":"127.0.0.1:21503","appium:ensureWebviewsHavePages":true,"appium:nativeWebScreenshot":true,"appium:newCommandTimeout":3600,"appium:connectHardwareKeyboard":true},"firstMatch":[{}]},"desiredCapabilities":{"platformName":"Android","appium:udid":"127.0.0.1:21503","appium:ensureWebviewsHavePages":true,"appium:nativeWebScreenshot":true,"appium:newCommandTimeout":3600,"appium:connectHardwareKeyboard":true}}
    [debug] [W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"platformName":"Android","appium:udid":"127.0.0.1:21503","appium:ensureWebviewsHavePages":true,"appium:nativeWebScreenshot":true,"appium:newCommandTimeout":3600,"appium:connectHardwareKeyboard":true},null,{"alwaysMatch":{"platformName":"Android","appium:udid":"127.0.0.1:21503","appium:ensureWebviewsHavePages":true,"appium:nativeWebScreenshot":true,"appium:newCommandTimeout":3600,"appium:connectHardwareKeyboard":true},"firstMatch":[{}]}]
    [debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1683902548058 (17:42:28 GMT+0300 (Восточная Европа, летнее время))
    [Appium]
    [Appium] ======================================================================
    [Appium]   DEPRECATION WARNING:
    [Appium]
    [Appium]   The 'automationName' capability was not provided in the desired
    [Appium]   capabilities for this Android session
    [Appium]
    [Appium]   Setting 'automationName=UiAutomator2' by default and using the
    [Appium]   UiAutomator2 Driver
    [Appium]
    [Appium]   The next major version of Appium (2.x) will **require** the
    [Appium]   'automationName' capability to be set for all sessions on all
    [Appium]   platforms
    [Appium]
    [Appium]   In previous versions (Appium <= 1.13.x), the default was
    [Appium]   'automationName=UiAutomator1'
    [Appium]
    [Appium]   If you wish to use that automation instead of UiAutomator2, please
    [Appium]   add 'automationName=UiAutomator1' to your desired capabilities
    [Appium]
    [Appium]   For more information about drivers, please visit
    [Appium]   http://appium.io/docs/en/about-appium/intro/ and explore the
    [Appium]   'Drivers' menu
    [Appium]
    [Appium] ======================================================================
    [Appium]
    [Appium] Appium v1.22.3 creating new AndroidUiautomator2Driver (v1.70.1) session
    [Appium] Explicitly enabling use of insecure features:
    [Appium]     chromdedriver_autodownload
    [debug] [BaseDriver] W3C capabilities and MJSONWP desired capabilities were provided
    [debug] [BaseDriver] Creating session with W3C capabilities: {
    [debug] [BaseDriver]   "alwaysMatch": {
    [debug] [BaseDriver]     "platformName": "Android",
    [debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:udid": "127.0.0.1:21503",
    [debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:ensureWebviewsHavePages": true,
    [debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:nativeWebScreenshot": true,
    [debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:newCommandTimeout": 3600,
    [debug] [BaseDriver]     "appium:connectHardwareKeyboard": true
    [debug] [BaseDriver]   },
    [debug] [BaseDriver]   "firstMatch": [
    [debug] [BaseDriver]     {}
    [debug] [BaseDriver]   ]
    [debug] [BaseDriver] }
    [BaseDriver] The following capabilities were provided, but are not recognized by Appium:
    [BaseDriver]   connectHardwareKeyboard
    [BaseDriver] Session created with session id: 4f1603de-708f-4320-b7c5-2d2fe025e3c9
    [UiAutomator2] Neither 'app' nor 'appPackage' was set. Starting UiAutomator2 without the target application
    [ADB] Found 19 'build-tools' folders under 'C:\Users\Default\Android\Sdk' (newest first):
    [ADB]     C:/Users/Default/Android/Sdk/build-tools/33.0.1
    [ADB]     C:/Users/Default/Android/Sdk/build-tools/32.0.0
    [ADB]     C:/Users/Default/Android/Sdk/build-tools/31.0.0
    [ADB]     C:/Users/Default/Android/Sdk/build-tools/30.0.3
    [ADB]     C:/Users/Default/Android/Sdk/build-tools/30.0.2
    [ADB]     C:/Users/Default/Android/Sdk/build-tools/30.0.1
    [ADB]     C:/Users/Default/Android/Sdk/build-tools/30.0.0
    [ADB]     C:/Users/Default/Android/Sdk/build-tools/29.0.3
    [ADB]     C:/Users/Default/Android/Sdk/build-tools/29.0.2
    [ADB]     C:/Users/Default/Android/Sdk/build-tools/29.0.1
    [ADB]     C:/Users/Default/Android/Sdk/build-tools/29.0.0
    [ADB]     C:/Users/Default/Android/Sdk/build-tools/28.0.3
    [ADB]     C:/Users/Default/Android/Sdk/build-tools/28.0.2
    [ADB]     C:/Users/Default/Android/Sdk/build-tools/28.0.1
    [ADB]     C:/Users/Default/Android/Sdk/build-tools/28.0.0
    [ADB]     C:/Users/Default/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.3
    [ADB]     C:/Users/Default/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2
    [ADB]     C:/Users/Default/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.1
    [ADB]     C:/Users/Default/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.0
    [ADB] Using 'adb.exe' from 'C:\Users\Default\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe'
    [debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Default\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 start-server'
    [AndroidDriver] Retrieving device list
    [debug] [ADB] Trying to find a connected android device
    [debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices
    [debug] [ADB] Connected devices: [{"udid":"127.0.0.1:21503","state":"device"}]
    [AndroidDriver] Using device: 127.0.0.1:21503
    [ADB] Using 'adb.exe' from 'C:\Users\Default\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe'
    [debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Default\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 start-server'
    [debug] [ADB] Setting device id to 127.0.0.1:21503
    [debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Default\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 127.0.0.1:21503 shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk'
    [debug] [ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.sdk': 28
    [ADB] Getting device platform version
    [debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Default\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 127.0.0.1:21503 shell getprop ro.build.version.release'
    [debug] [ADB] Current device property 'ro.build.version.release': 9
    [debug] [ADB] Device API level: 28
    [UiAutomator2] Relaxing hidden api policy
    [debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Default\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 127.0.0.1\:21503 shell 'settings put global hidden_api_policy_pre_p_apps 1;settings put global hidden_api_policy_p_apps 1;settings put global hidden_api_policy 1''
    [AndroidDriver] No app sent in, not parsing package/activity
    [debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Default\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 127.0.0.1:21503 wait-for-device'
    [debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Default\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 127.0.0.1:21503 shell echo ping'
    [debug] [AndroidDriver] Pushing settings apk to device...
    [debug] [ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.settings
    [debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Default\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 127.0.0.1:21503 shell dumpsys package io.appium.settings'
    [debug] [ADB] 'io.appium.settings' is not installed
    [debug] [ADB] App 'C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\io.appium.settings\apks\settings_apk-debug.apk' is not installed
    [debug] [ADB] Installing 'C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\io.appium.settings\apks\settings_apk-debug.apk'
    [debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Default\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 127.0.0.1:21503 help'
    [debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Default\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 127.0.0.1:21503 features'
    [ADB] The application at 'C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\io.appium.settings\apks\settings_apk-debug.apk' will not be cached, because the device under test has confirmed the support of streamed installs
    [debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Default\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 127.0.0.1:21503 install -g C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\io.appium.settings\apks\settings_apk-debug.apk'
    [debug] [ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.settings
    [debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Default\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 127.0.0.1:21503 shell dumpsys package io.appium.settings'
    [debug] [ADB] 'io.appium.settings' is not installed
    [debug] [ADB] App 'C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\io.appium.settings\apks\settings_apk-debug.apk' is not installed
    [debug] [ADB] Installing 'C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\io.appium.settings\apks\settings_apk-debug.apk'
    [ADB] The application at 'C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\io.appium.settings\apks\settings_apk-debug.apk' will not be cached, because the device under test has confirmed the support of streamed installs
    [debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Default\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 127.0.0.1:21503 install -g C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\io.appium.settings\apks\settings_apk-debug.apk'
    [debug] [UiAutomator2] Deleting UiAutomator2 session
    [UiAutomator2] Restoring hidden api policy to the device default configuration
    [debug] [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\Default\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 127.0.0.1\:21503 shell 'settings delete global hidden_api_policy_pre_p_apps;settings delete global hidden_api_policy_p_apps;settings delete global hidden_api_policy''
    [debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1683902550290 (17:42:30 GMT+0300 (Восточная Европа, летнее время))
    [debug] [W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C:\\Users\\Default\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 127.0.0.1\:21503 install -g C:\\Users\\Администратор\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\io.appium.settings\\apks\\settings_apk-debug.apk' exited with code 1'; Command output: adb: failed to install C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\io.appium.settings\apks\settings_apk-debug.apk:
    [debug] [W3C] Exception occurred while executing:
    [debug] [W3C] java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.endsWith(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    [debug] [W3C]   at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runInstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:968)
    [debug] [W3C]   at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:179)
    [debug] [W3C]   at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:103)
    [debug] [W3C]   at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageM
    [debug] [W3C] Error: Command 'C:\\Users\\Default\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 127.0.0.1\:21503 install -g C:\\Users\\Администратор\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\io.appium.settings\\apks\\settings_apk-debug.apk' exited with code 1
    [debug] [W3C]     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\teen_process\lib\exec.js:113:19)
    [debug] [W3C]     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    [debug] [W3C]     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
    [debug] [W3C]     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
    [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 2486 ms - 2747
```

Обновление:

Поставил Appium v2.0.0-beta.66, ошибка не поменялась
При установке всех необходимых apk вручную, инспектор дает доступ, но я получаю пустое окно

[image: Скрин с инспектора]